# Passing object as parameter in route returns [Object object]

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing, angular-router

This is in my routing.module:

```
{path: 'hero' component: HeroComponent}
```

And this is how I pass the object though route:

```
this.router.createUrlTree(['/hero', {my_object: this.Obj}]));
window.open(url, '_blank');
```

In my hero component I read object like:

```
this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('my_object');
```

console.log(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('my_object');) returns:

```
[Object object]
```

and reading a property of object for example `.id` returns:

```
undefined
```

If I try to iterate it with `*ngFor` I get:

```
ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'string'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: there are two options.
1. try to use like this `this.router.createUrlTree(['/hero', this.Obj]));`, this.Obj is already a object.
2. If this does not work, can you please share structure of this.Obj ?

Comment: @piyushjain The answer bellow worked, however how would I retrieve this.Object once I am in my component? `this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get(?);`? What should I put there since I don't have property `my_object`  before?

Comment: you can retrieve it using this `this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => {}`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to send a string using `JSON.stringify()`

```js
this.router.createUrlTree(['/hero', {my_object: JSON.stringify(this.Obj)}]));
```

and parse it back it in the recipient

```js
this.Obj = JSON.parse(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('my_object'));
```

And if the `Obj` variable is an object, you need to use `keyvalue` pipe to iterate over it using `*ngFor` directive

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of Obj | keyvalue">
  {{ item.key }}: {{ item.value }}
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Looks a little bit hacky but worked, thanks a lot